# Cannot open sharing dialog from a Chrome app

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a Chrome app that saves files to Drive. That part works okay. I would like to access the sharing dialog too, but I get errors:

Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.google.com chrome-extension://hekghfoflcbaaaklbeghliclfkcgfjio"

Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=wise&continue=https%3A%2…rigin%3Dchrome-extension%3A%2F%2Fhekghfoflcbaaaklbeghliclfkcgfjio%23&hl=en' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

There are a few more of these; I'm not sure including them all is useful.

It seems to me that the CSP errors may be caused by the API doing script element injection? Unfortunately I can't use 'unsafe-inline' in a Chrome app manifest; that isn't allowed.

Another possible issue is this:

"The JS origin of the host page must match the origin of either the create or open URLs in the Drive SDK settings (protocol/host/port must match)"

As this is a locally installed extension (installed from the Chrome web store), there is no create or open URL I can provide, as far as I can tell (chrome-extension:// URLs are not allowed in the Drive SDK app settings page).

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* specify chrome-extension URLs for your javascript origin, although I don't think  that that is the cause of your error.

Comment: how do you specify the url? I get this "Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are allowed." when I try "chrome-extension://pfebkgbfppbgnmobaphilohfbipfanhh/"